# Why doesn't sublime show inside this directory with a link symbol on it?

Tags: sublimetext3

In this case "src". And how can I get it to show up? Editing some setting? See picture. [image]

Comment: Is it possible that the icon is representing a symlink?  Seems like there are [preventive measures in place to prevent indexing symlinks](https://github.com/SublimeTextIssues/Core/issues/2325).  This looks like Ubuntu, right?

Comment: @Brian, Have you found the solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

When you open a folder in Sublime, it crawls the entire folder in order to come up with a complete catalog of every file and folder that exists within that particular folder, so that it can be displayed in the side bar, indexed for symbols, and so on. This is the reason why it's not a good idea to open the root of an entire drive or a large structure like your home directory, for example.

Folders with a link on them are Symbolic Links to other folders that have already been seen in the folder tree. Sublime doesn't look inside them because it's impossible to detect if the link ultimately ends up causing the traversal to end up back where it started, which would end up scanning the same folder tree forever until memory runs out.

As such there is no setting that controls being able to look inside such a folder. However if you right click on it, there is an optional entitled `Reveal Link Source` that will show you what it's linking to.

The determination of what's a link and what is not is done by comparing the underlying folder information from the OS (e.g. on Linux it would compare the inode); the first time one is seen, it's added, and all other references to the same data are considered links.

As a side note, in rare cases this has been known to run afoul of poorly designed file systems (such as those that expose a remote file system locally) that don't properly identify items. The console tells you when links are found. That's only of interest if the item in your screenshot actually is **not** a symlink, though.

Comment: I have an issue where this happens with folders that are not symlinks yet sibling folders have the same subfolders/contents so if I have two directories each with two subdirectories and the sub directories have the same names, it shows up with the link icon and isn't openable. It's incredibly frustrating and the only workaround I've found is to add extra cruft files to make those sub directories actually different or adding the specific folders to the project separately