# Getting some icon over the folder in a sublime text editor

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext, text-editor

I am using MacBook Air, I am using Sublime text editor for the last two years. It was working but from yesterday, I am getting some kind of icon on my folder. I am not able to understand why I am getting this. I have my files inside that folder and I am Not able to click on the folder as well. When I check in another text editor then my folder is working.

Please check below image

[image]

Can anyone know this issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why doesn't sublime show inside this directory with a link symbol on it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55435445/why-doesnt-sublime-show-inside-this-directory-with-a-link-symbol-on-it)

Comment: @KeithHall, I read that answer but doesn't help me. I open my project folder and my folder structure is
Example
-assets
--CSS
--doc
--fonts
--img
--Include
--js
-Index.php
-about.php